# Drawing results of calcOpticalFlowFarneback in OpenCV without loop

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, opticalflow

I am using `cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback()` in python to obtain results of optical flow but there's a problem while trying to use it's results. I want to draw the change returned by that function but looping in python is too slow. I am sure there's a method with numpy to make it faster. Here's my attempt

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev_gray, gray, pyr_scale=0.5, levels=5, winsize=13, iterations=10, poly_n=5, poly_sigma=1.1, flags=0,flow=None) 

for y in range(0, flow.shape[0], 5):

    for x in range(0, flow.shape[1], 5):

        fx, fy = flow[y, x]

        cv2.line(frame2, (x,y), (int(x+fx),int(y+fy)), (255,0,0))
        cv2.circle(frame2, (x,y), 1, (255,0,0), -1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the openCV method cv2.polylines() to draw an array of polygonal curves without having to to iterate with a for loop.

here is a code sample

```
   def draw_flow(self, img, flow, step=16):
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    y, x = np.mgrid[step / 2:h:step, step / 2:w:step].reshape(2, -1).astype(int)
    fx, fy = flow[y, x].T
    lines = np.vstack([x, y, x + fx, y + fy]).T.reshape(-1, 2, 2)
    lines = np.int32(lines + 0.5)
    vis = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cv2.polylines(vis, lines, 0, (0, 255, 0))
    for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in lines:
        cv2.circle(vis, (x1, y1), 1, (0, 255, 0), -1)
    return vis
```

check out the openCV samples to download and run the full code https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/opt_flow.py

or the openCV documentation to get more info on polylines http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html#polylines